# How to do list with buttons c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I am making a `WindowsFormsApplication` in C# and I want to make a list that looks like that:

```
#      Item     Edit Delete
1      Item1     [E]  [X]
2      Item2     [E]  [X]
3      Item3     [E]  [X]
```

and I want to make [E] and [X] to be clickable buttons. How to do that? I'm relatively new to this so please be gentle

Comment: you need to use a `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hugo is correct DataGridView will do it.
If you look at the Columns property you can define the column types, the default is for text but there is a button type too.
When the click event is triggered you can check the selected row/column properties to deduce which button was clicked.

Comment: ok, thanks. Another question, is it possible to remove that first default column?

Comment: Ignore that, found what I needed. thanks for the help :)